# Can linux device-mapper be used to throttle disk IO?

Tags: linux, device-mapper

The [device-mapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_mapper) framework of the linux kernel offers many useful modes of operation or targets.

Some prominent are:

- [dm-crypt](https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/device-mapper/dm-crypt.txt) allowing to include [encryption of block devices](https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/device-mapper/dm-crypt.txt)
- [dm-raid](https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/device-mapper/dm-raid.txt) for multi device raid purposes

There is also some like:

- [dm-delay](https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/device-mapper/delay.txt) that "delays reads and/or writes and maps them to different devices."
- dm-flakey

which seem more applicable for tests, developement, benchmarking and debugging.

I was hoping to find also one "dm-iothrottle' which I imagined to allow limiting the read and write speed. Unfortunately a "dm-iothrottle" seems not to exist.

My question is if there is something, which I might have overlooked that provides the functionality, to put a max limit on the io throughput, via the device-mapper feature.

My temporary solution has been to do this

```
while sleep 1 
do 
  dm-setup suspend /dev/dm-X
  sleep 1
  dm-setup resume /dev/dm-X
done
```

which sort of halves the throuput, given that the mapping is suspended half of the time.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: `dm-delay` lets you set up the latency. It seems to be what you are after. Check this: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/device-mapper/delay.html

Comment: @EduardoTrápani thank you. on  the linked page I have not seen some indication how to setup "latency", but only an initial delay. This does not result in the desired throttling effect, as reading `20GiB` would only have a one time of initial delay and then be full speed, at least that is how I read the information on that site. Maybe you know more?

Comment: What's the use case? Because there's caching too: with a filesystem on top of it, or with the block device itself (as long as it's kept open somewhere, or the cache gets flushed on last close).

Comment: @A.B benchmarking. I need to simulate a slow disk and the brd (block ram device) is excessively fast

Comment: cgroups can limit the I/O. v1 limits blocks adequately. v2 can do better with limiting block+cache. You could take a look there: https://andrestc.com/post/cgroups-io/